Determine if inner product over a real vector space has a certain form
Verify if the following statement is true: Every inner product on $\mathbb{R}^n$ has the form $\langle v,u\rangle = v(Au),$ where $A$ is a symmetric matrix with positive entries on the diagonal.

I think this is false, but I don't have a concrete counterexample. However, I think a similar statement is true: Asume  $A$ is symmetric but eliminate the condition that $A$ has positive diagonal entries.

It is true. Just define the $(i,j)-$ element of $A$ as inner product of $e_i$ and $e_j$.

@geetha290krm Thanks! The vectors $e_k$ you mentioned belong to an arbitrary orthonormal basis? Or do they belong specifically to the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Standard basis.

It is indeed true, and more: the matrix $A$ can be taken to be the identiity if the coordinates are changed. One can apply a Gram-Schimdt ortogonalization process, with respect to the inner product in question, to the canonical basis to produce a ortonormal basis $f = (f_1, \dots, f_n)$ to this inner product. Then it is simple to verify that if $u = (u_1, \dots, u_n)_f$ and $v = (v_1, \dots, v_n)_f$, then $\langle u, v \rangle = u_1v_1 + \cdots + u_nv_n$.
